finding vertices of a rhombus given the equations of a side passing through a point and a diagonal
considering a rhombus ABCD,
sides AB and AC are represented by the equations $x-y+1=0$ and $2x-y-1=0$ respectively, if the line BC passes through the point E=(5,-6). find the equation of the sides BC, CD, DA
my idea to approach this problem was as below.
$$l_1 \equiv x-y+1 = 0 $$
$$l_2 \equiv 2x-y-1 = 0$$
since AC and AB are intersecting at A, using simultaneous equations
$$A = (2,3)$$
to find the angle CAB which is $\theta$,
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{2-1}{1+2*1} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\theta = \arctan(\frac{1}{3})$$
since diagonal bisects the angle DAB, and since DA passes through A
$$\frac{y-3}{x-2} = \tan(2\arctan(\frac{1}{3}))$$
the problem is i plot that equation in Desmos with the other 2, but it didn't exactly made it look like l2 is the angular bisector, my idea was to find the line such that l2 is the angular bisector of that line (lets say l3) and l1, so that is DA, and use the gradient to find the parallel line at (5,-6) which is l4, find the intersect C using l4 and l2, find the parallel of l1 at C
what did i do wrong when finding the angle?

$2tan^{-1}{1/3}$ is angle between sides AB and AD. You’re taking slope of AD as $tan2\theta$ which is wrong. Slope means angle is taken with +ve x-axis. So correct slope of AD would be $tan^{-1}m_{AB}+ tan^{-1}{2\theta}$

oh, thank you for seeing my mistake
